# JMS JPA concurrency issue on Websphere App Server 7, EJB 3.0, OpenJPA EntityExistsException

Tags: jpa, jms, ejb-3.0, openjpa

Use case is a Device sending JMS messages with GPS info processed by a MDB. If a Device doesn't exist in the database then it is created/inserted and the GPS record created/inserted. Everything works fine when messages are handled as they are sent. The issue occurs when messages from the same device build up and are processed within miliseconds of each other. There seems to be a race condition of one JMS message process inserting an entity inbetween the time that another JMS process checks for the entity (and it does not exist) and attempts to insert the entity (and it is already there).

The process is attempting to insert the Device entity multiple times because at some point the process finds no record exists. The following exception is thrown because the record has been inserted by a previous message being processed. I've tried changing the IsolationLevels to every value up to SERIALIZABLE with no luck. Any ideas would be much appreciated! WAS 7, OpenJPA 2.0.2, EJB3.0

```
[8/30/12 11:14:01:319 EDT] 0000002a RegisteredSyn E   WTRN0074E: Exception caught
  from before_completion synchronization operation:
  <openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1295351 fatal store error>
  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: The transaction has been
  rolled back. See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.

Caused by: <openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1295351 fatal store error>
  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: ORA-00001:
  unique constraint (SPW_OWN.PK_DEVICE) violated
```

SSB snippet doing the process:

```
                Device device = deviceManager.findDeviceByDeviceI(deviceString);

                //check to see if device entity exists
                if(device == null){
                    Log.logDebug(this, "device " + deviceString +" is null");

                    device.setDeviceI(deviceString);

                    //tried both create and update with no luck
                    //deviceManager.createDevice(device);

                    deviceManager.updateDevice(device);
                }
```

JPA SSB:

```
@Action(Action.ACTION_TYPE.UPDATE)
public String updateDevice(Device device) throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        device = em.merge(device);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Doing some testing i have found a decent work around though I'm still not 100% satisfied. Any other suggestions will be welcome:

- Set the JMS MDB in a Bean Managed transaction type and keep the other subsequent SSBs in Container mode so that I can still have the actual data operations Container managed for rollback.
- Set a programmatic threshold in the MDB to retry and process the message X amount of times.
- Catch the EJBTransactionRolledbackException (caused by the EntityExistsException) when the SSB is invoked
- Retry to process the message again using the threshold (in my case the second time was successful because the previous transaction was committed and the retry found that the entity exists and sucessfully processed the message)
- I set my threshold programatically to try and process the message twice before sending it to an error queue.

I don't normally like to use exception catching as a control flow. I also imagine there is a way to keep the JMS MDB as Container Managed transaction and have the Java EE server re-process the message.

Comment: Could you catch the EntityExistsException and handle appropriately?

Comment: That was my initial idea as well, to catch the EEE and then simply requery to get the entity. The exception is being thrown in the Container Managed Transaction when the transaction is committed so the code calling the updateDevice or createDevice never gets the exception...

Comment: What about calling em.flush() to force pushing the data to the DB?